# SSRS - hard code locale into expression

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to format the number like this 1.212,89 but because of the regional settings of the server, I always end up with 1,212.89. Is it possible to hard code the locale into field expression?

The example below works, but I need to format field value Fields!FieldName.Value instead of manually entering the number.

`=(new Decimal(1.212,89)).ToString("€#,0.00;(€#,0.00)",new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-ES"))`

Is it possible?
Thanks for advice.

Comment: Are you sure it's the regional settings of the server, rather than of the report? You can set the [locale setting for the report, or even for a given text box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159642.aspx). (Also, if you want Fields!FieldName, just drag it in there from the expression editor...)

Comment: I honesly didn't know about possibility of setting Locale in Properties. It solved my problem! Thank you very much!

Comment: Okay, cool, in that case I'll post it as an answer so you can accept it.

Comment: That would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the locale properties independently for both the report and individual textboxes of the report. See [this MSDN article for more details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159642.aspx), but basically you just alter it as a property on the appropriate objects.